# SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild on VSTS with SSL

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

I have been pulling my hair over this one.
I use VSTS as part of my build process and as a step I set up the use of SonarQube using the new sonar scanner extensions.
I have set up a SonarQube VM on Azure using SSL by the way of a reverse proxy (nginx) as newer versions of SonarQube do not accept SSL and I don't really want http for that.
The certificate I use is valid - it is not self-signed - it is a normal wildcard certificate for our domain and the VM I set up is part of that domain.
The problem is that when the analysis has run and reach the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild - End Analysis (new) step, I get SSL errors:

> ### [error]12:50:05.455 ERROR: SonarQube server [https://x.domain.com/sonar] can not be reached
>
> ...
>
> ### [error]Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
>
> ...
>
> ### [error]Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

If I understand the issue well - it may well be I haven't - it seems that the VSTS agent "java" environment doesn't have the certificate it is own keyStore ??

So, in a nutshell, is there a way to make this VSTS extension work with a Sonar on SSL ?

Please note that I use the latest version of sonarQube and the latest of the VSTS sonar extensions.

Comment: Do you use private build agent? Try to import certificate in KeyStore and use that KeyStore. [How to Configure SonarQube plugin for HTTPS Sonar Server?](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001445548-How-to-Configure-SonarQube-plugin-for-HTTPS-Sonar-Server-)

Comment: No I am using the agent hosted on VSTS so not sure I have any control over this ?

Comment: You need to setup a private build agent. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-windows

Comment: Ok thanks I will do that.